# How to make a sum of every field's value in every section in acumatica report designer?

Tags: acumatica

Background: There are multiple Sub Reports depending on the number of sections in the main report. In each section, they have a value called Qty, and I would like to get the sum of the Qty for each row / sub report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sub-report, create a variable to hold the value sum of Qty.
In your main report, you can reference the variable inside like this

```
$subreportName_variableName
```

So the above expression is added to a textbox inside the main report, in order to retrieve the value of sub-report field.